# Storing different values in one same field database php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this two tables, 
**exam table**

```
ID, title, creator
```

**exam_settings table**

```
id //(simply for managing rows and edits/updates)
"1", "2", "3" // etc

quiz_id
"55912" // or so on

type
"question", "answer"

ref_number
"1", "2" // This is basically Question 1, Question 2, Answer 1 etc.

value
"What is ...?" or "21" // The question or the answer
```

Now I have a problem storing the question and answer in the table, I used this html array question
`<input type="text"  name="quiztxtBox[]" > and <input type="text"  name="answer[]" >` 
to get the inputs. But I wonder how to perform sql using this 2 arrays and store them in same field. Here is how my sql looks like.

```
$quiztxtBox = $_POST["quiztxtBox"]; //array
$answer = $_POST["answer"]; //array

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("elearning") or die(mysql_error()) ;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO exam_list (exam_name, creator) VALUES ('$files', 'admin')");

$lastid = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM exam_list ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");
$id = implode($lastid);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO exam_setting (exam_id, type, ref_number, value) VALUES ('$id', 'othervalues')");
```

So I stored first the exam name and creator the after the exam questions and answer, thats the part where I am lost. Any Idea on this?

Comment: You do not need to use a query for the last insert id, use php's mysql_insert_id

Comment: oh i see, thanks for that.. How about the main questioN?

Comment: whats the relation between exam table and exam_setting table? How will you join these tables?

Comment: You would then get quiz by id = 55912, and check against quiz settings for all with "quiz_id" == 55912, and using the "question" field and "ref_number" field, you generate a table or page which has the questions, and then a field which has to be equal to "answer" "1"

Comment: You should check SQL JOINs

Comment: uhmm.. the problem here is how to store the question and answer which is on the same field.

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: thanks for the info, but that does not answer the question.

Comment: @user3627265 that's why he put it in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: How are the questions linked to the answers?

Comment: do you just want to merge two arrays and then turn them into a string to store in single database field/column...?  what format are you trying to store things in?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the values of input text as array by this way.

```
<form name="" action="array.php" method="post">
<input type="text"  name="quiztxtBox[]" >
<input type="text"  name="answer[]" >
</form>
```

In array.php file

```
//get the array
$quiztxtBox=$_POST['quiztxtBox'];
$answer=$_POST['answer'];
//loop through the array
foreach($quiztxtBox as $key=>$quiztxtBox){

 echo 'Question'.$quiztxtBox.'Answer'.$answer[$key];
 //for storing in the same field.
 //perform your sql query with this
$finalstring=$quiztxtBox.','.$answer[$key];


}
```